# How to write an empty value for points on Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm developing Windows Form app using Graph API. I have Excel file with data from Teams. Excel columns are: Display name, Feedback, Points, Submission id, OutcomeFeedback id and OutcomePoints id. I want to update the value of points in the Excel file and write that value on Teams. The problem is that when I leave the field for points empty, I get an error. Does anyone know how to solve this? Here is the code:

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
                        {
                            string cellValue1 = Convert.ToString(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value); //feedback
                            string cellValue2 = Convert.ToString(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value); //points
                            string cellValue3 = Convert.ToString(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 4].Value); //submission id
                            string cellValue4 = Convert.ToString(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 5].Value); //outcome feedback id
                            string cellValue5 = Convert.ToString(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value); //outcome points 

                            if(cellValue1 == null)
                            {
                                await GraphHelper.UpdateFeedback("", this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue4);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await GraphHelper.UpdateFeedback(cellValue1, this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue4);
                            }

                            if(cellValue2 == null)
                            {
                                await GraphHelper.UpdatePoints("", this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue5);
                            }
                            else if(Int32.Parse(cellValue2) <= 100 && Int32.Parse(cellValue2) >= 0)
                            {
                                await GraphHelper.UpdatePoints(cellValue2, this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue5);
                            }
                        }

public static async Task UpdatePoints(string points, string teamId, string assignmentId, string submissionId, string outcomeId)
    {
        graphClient = GetGraphClient(token);

        var educationOutcomePoint = new EducationPointsOutcome
        {
            Points = new EducationAssignmentPointsGrade
            {
                Points = Int32.Parse(points)
            }
        };

        await GraphHelper.graphClient.Education.Classes[teamId].Assignments[assignmentId].Submissions[submissionId].Outcomes[outcomeId]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(educationOutcomePoint);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible in your case you can use 0 instead empty string. The exception is probably thrown when you are trying to parse empty string `Int32.Parse(points)`.

```
...
if(cellValue1 == null)
{
    await GraphHelper.UpdateFeedback("0", this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue4);
}
else
{
    await GraphHelper.UpdateFeedback(cellValue1, this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue4);
}
if(cellValue2 == null)
{
    await GraphHelper.UpdatePoints("0", this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue5);
}
else if(Int32.Parse(cellValue2) <= 100 && Int32.Parse(cellValue2) >= 0)
{
    await GraphHelper.UpdatePoints(cellValue2, this.team_id, assignment_id, cellValue3, cellValue5);
}
...
```